# Conditional Joins | SQL | Optimizing performance and reduce no. of JOINS

Tags: sql, join, impala

I have the following tables:

t1:

```
create table t1 (auth_date string,
                 auth_nbr int,
                 debit_date string,
                 debit_nbr int,
                 txn_dttm string,
                 iss_id string,
                 audit_num int);

insert into t1 values 
('01-05-2021',12,null,null,'01-05-2021','b',124),
(null,null,'02-05-2021',13,'02-05-2021','c',125),
('02-05-2021',14,'02-05-2021',14,'02-05-2021','d',126);
```

t2:

```
create table t2 (txn_amt int,txn_dttm string,iss_id string,audit_num int);

insert into t2 values 
(2000,'01-05-2021','b',124),
(2500,'02-05-2021','c',125),
(1000,'02-05-2021','d',126);
```

How I want my output:

```
dw_date|dw_nbr|amt
01-05-2021|12|2000
02-05-2021|13|2500
02-05-2021|14|1000
```

I have the below query. But since joining is a heavy operation and I want to narrow it down to 1 join only. But my joining in both cases is different conditions i.e in the first condition join is on 3 cols and in another join is on 2 cols. I wanted to find a way on how I can achieve the desired output. Conditional Joins. Or anything else.
From the t2 table, I just need the relevant txn_amt.

```
select dw_date,dw_nbr,amt 
from (select t1.auth_date,t1.auth_nbr,t2.amt from t1 join t2 on t1.txn_dttm=t2.txn_dttm and t1.iss_id=t2.iss_id and t1.audit_num=t2.audit_num 
where auth_date is not null and auth_nbr is not null and debit_date is null and debit_nbr is null)a 
union all 
select dw_date,dw_nbr,amt 
from (select t1.debit_date,t1.debit_nbr,t2.amt from t1 join t2 on t1.txn_dttm=t2.txn_dttm and t1.audit_num=t2.audit_num 
where debit_date is not null and debit_nbr is not null)a;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this one. As latest version of MYSQL is using so use CTE for avoiding multiple use of large tables.

```
-- MySQL(v5.8)
WITH a_cte AS (
    SELECT t1.auth_date, t1.auth_nbr, t2.txn_amt
         , t1.debit_date, t1.debit_nbr
         , CASE WHEN t1.iss_id = t2.iss_id
                   THEN 1
                ELSE 0
           END iss_id
    FROM t1
    INNER JOIN t2
            ON t1.txn_dttm = t2.txn_dttm 
           AND t1.audit_num = t2.audit_num 
), b_cte AS (
    SELECT auth_date AS dw_date
         , auth_nbr AS dw_nbr
         , txn_amt AS amt
    FROM a_cte
    WHERE iss_id = 1
        AND auth_date is not null 
        AND auth_nbr is not null 
        AND debit_date is null 
        AND debit_nbr is null
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT debit_date AS dw_date
         , debit_nbr AS dw_nbr
         , txn_amt AS amt
    FROM a_cte
    WHERE debit_date is not null 
        AND debit_nbr is not null 
)
SELECT *
FROM b_cte;
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1a482589e2cdc1f6b288c93f88150fa5

Comment: Hi @AnukritiSingh please check this one. Hope you'll get your desired result and also get better performance. Please let me know if any query regard this.

Comment: The question is tagged for impala, not mysql. Are you sure this is a correct answer?

Comment: @RahulBiswas. Thanks for the answer. I will validate and let you know.

Comment: @AnukritiSingh did my given answer help you?

Comment: @RahulBiswas, yes it helped me. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Thanks @AnukritiSingh please mark as accepted along with useful so that others can encourage to pick that answer in future. Please don't take it otherwise.

Comment: Welcome. Thanks for your response. You've marked it as useful but not accepted this answer. If do so then green tick mark is shown.